# How can I create this complicated dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a heck of a time trying to create a dictionary for a script I am trying to write that handles different IP addresses.

My question is this:

Given `d1` and `d2`, and assuming `d1` and `d2` will always have an equal number of key:pair items,
how can I create `d3`?

```
d1 = {1:a, 2:b, 3:b, 4:c, 5:c}

d2 = {one:a, two:b, three:b, four:c, five:c}

d3 = {a:[{1:one}], b:[{2:two},{3:three}], c:[{4:four},{5:five}]}
```

You can see `d3` contains keys that are the same as the values from `d1` and `d2`, and for each key in `d3`, it has a value of a list, in which there are more dictionaries with key:pair values that correspond to the original keys from `d1` and `d2`.

I have been trying to create `d3` for a while now but I just can't seem to reason out how to do it. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any examples of what you've tried? What did you get as output? You've shown us what you *wanted*, which is fantastic - but it's also a good idea to show us the effort you've put into solving the problem on your own. Which can be super helpful if all you need is to correct some small misunderstanding

Comment: How do you expect `d3` to know that "2" and "two" go together? If it were `b:[{3:two},{2:three}]` would that still be good? May I remind you that dictionaries in python don't preserve order..

Comment: Ofir, it would not work if 2:two and 3:three did not go together. Those two dictionaries can appear in any order within the list, but the key:value in each of those dictionaries must be how I listed it.

Answer (score 1):

First tip before giving out the answer :

```
reverse_d1 = {}
for k, v in d1.iteritems():
  reverse_d1.set_default(v, []).append(k)
```

Comment: Thomas, let me give that a try and see what I can do. I have tried a number of things including adding the values from the beginning two dictionaries to a list, etc.. Everything I've done has not worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

All, thank you for the input. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I realized that the way I currently posed the question, it is completely invalid. The keys in d2 correspond to subnet masks, which are not all unique, so the way I had it structured is not even a valid dictionary.

After a lot of fussing, I came up with a working solution:

```
p = 0
sysNames = ['R3','R2','R1']
d1 = OrderedDict([('200.200.200.2','R3'),('200.200.200.1','R2'),('172.172.172.1','R2'),('172.172.172.100','R1'),('192.168.1.151','R1')])

oid1 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.200.200.200.2'
oid2 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.200.200.200.1'
oid3 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.172.172.172.1'
oid4 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.172.172.172.100'
oid5 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.192.168.1.151'

d2 = {oid1:'255.255.255.0',oid2:'255.255.255.0',oid3:'255.255.255.0',oid4:'255.255.255.0',oid5:'255.255.255.0'}

d1keys = list(d1.keys())
d1values = list(d1.values())
maskOid = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.'

d3 = {}

for i in range(len(sysNames)):
    ipMaskList = list()
    numInterfaces = d1values.count(sysNames[i])

    for dummy in range(numInterfaces):
        ipMaskList.append({d1keys[p]:d2.get(maskOid+d1keys[p])})
        p += 1

    d3[sysNames[i]] = ipMaskList
```

As typical, I'm sure this is a horribly inefficient and convoluted way to accomplish my goal. I am absolutely not a great programmer, and am just happy when things run correctly.

Again thank you guys you your help, and if anybody would like to post a more efficient solution, please feel free :)